# How do I submit an HTML form to a Popup windows with resize disabled?

Tags: html

I had designed an HTML form with submit button. But instead of submit it to another page I  want to submit to pop up windows where I can limit the size of the pop up windows say "320x240" hide all the toolbar, disable resize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my go at it; this JavaScript snippet should go into the head of your page:

```
<script>
process = function()
 {
    window.open('about:blank', 'popup', 'width=320,height=240,resizeable=no');
    document.login.setAttribute('target', 'popup');
    document.login.setAttribute('onsubmit', '');
    document.login.submit();
 };
</script>
```

And this is a sample form for demonstration purposes:

```
<form action="handle.html" method="get" name="login" onsubmit="process(); return false;">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now, here's what's happening: first, we set up a form and give it an `onsubmit` attribute that tells it to run the function `process()` and `return false;` instead of submitting normally; from this point, that function takes over and creates a popup window, giving it a name, and some features (by all means, add any surplus ones you'd like), and then attention comes back to the form, where we now set the `target` attribute to the name of the window we just created.

We then have to clear that `onsubmit` that we set earlier, or this same exact thing will happen again, and that's certainly not what you want. Finally, we just have the form submitted again and it now passes all of its information to the popped window; from there, it's just getting `handle.html` (or whatever you end up calling your processing page) to do its work with the data.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using post instead of get?  I of course got it working your way, but then simply changing method to post in the form tag didn't work.  Post is supposedly more secure than get, thus you should try to use it whenever possible.

Comment: I did it with post instead of get with no problem! although my code varies a little, my form: `<form id="theForm" name="theForm" action="yourPage.php" method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)" >` and my js function : `function target_popup(form) {
    w = window.open('', 'metas_pop', 'width=1000,height=600,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'metas_pop';
    w.focus();
}` . also, as a plus notice that i added the w.focus() to open the popup right away, even if it was already open but without focus (e.g. from a previous submit). Hope it works for you