# Form Submission As A Pop Up in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying a form submission to a page as a pop up window. I tried the solution in the following link.

[How do I submit an HTML form to a Popup windows with resize disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660810/how-do-i-submit-an-html-form-to-a-popup-windows-with-resize-disabled)

It works fine on Chrome and IE but fails on Mozilla.. Can i know why and how to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a demo in which you elaborate how it's failing on Firefox.

Comment: It opens as a blank page with no url submissions. that is the basic problem.. Thank you

Comment: Please provide your current code.  I'll set up the test case if you do.

Comment: @Abilash, I mean a demo (a webpage) in which you show the issue. You can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or provide a link to your website.

Comment: it's exactly the same except i have 4 more fields inside the form and it's post method

Comment: [It's working fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/6CFyb/).

Comment: Sure i'll provide a fiddle in a moment

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/6CFyb/1/
It doesnt work

Comment: Your html is invalid.  Provide quotes around your action link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you named your form something else, but never referred to it in the javascript.  The following worked for me:

```
process = function() {
    window.open('about:blank', 'popup', 'width=320,height=240,resizeable=no');
    document.startChat.setAttribute('target', 'popup');
    document.startChat.setAttribute('onsubmit', '');
    document.startChat.submit();
}
```

Comment: no that wasnt the problem i got.. i had used window.location before this code... i modified an existing fiddle.. that was y it was not modified... thank you very much for your help...

Comment: Then please post the code for your processing page.  I had a dirt-simple `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` and it worked fine.