# How to popup the search result

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the results on the popup screen, but I don't know what to put in de '()'. hope you guy's can help me with this problem. thanks :D

```
<script>
// JavaScript popup window function
function basicPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(url,'action','height=550,width=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes')
}
</script>

<form method=GET action="http://www.google.com/search">

        <input type=hidden name=ie value=UTF-8>
        <input type=hidden name=oe value=UTF-8>

<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <input Type=text name=q size=31 maxlength=255 value="">
        <input Type=submit name=btnG value="Search" onclick="basicPopup();return false">

    <font size=-1>
        <input type=hidden name=domains value="google">
        <input type=hidden name=sitesearch value="google.com" checked>
    </font>

</table>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/G4T8Z/

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
// JavaScript popup window function
function basicPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(url,'action','height=550,width=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes')
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method=GET action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input type=hidden name=ie value=UTF-8>
    <input type=hidden name=oe value=UTF-8>
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <input Type=text name=q id=q size=31 maxlength=255 value="">
        <input type=submit name=btnG value="Search" onclick="basicPopup('https://www.google.bg/search?q=' + document.getElementById('q').value); return false"> <font size=-1>
        <input type=hidden name=domains value="google">
        <input type=hidden name=sitesearch value="google.com" checked>
    </font>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but the problem now is that the value='google.com'(name=sitesearch) doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want to do? Use the "sitesearch" field value to specify if the search has to use bing, google, eso?

Answer (score 0):

In **onclick="basicPopup();** pass the html page or website url where you want to pass these values .

```
ex. onclick="basicPopup('D:\new.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am revising my answer altogether, because I didn't originally understand that you were looking to post the entire form to the pop-up.

You need to name your form so that you can reference it from javascript. Then you need to access the form after the popup has been created and change its target to the newly created popup. Finally you programatically submit the form and it gets posted to into the popup.

Here's what the code looks like after those changes:

```
<script>
        // JavaScript popup window function
        function basicPopup(url) {
            popupWindow = window.open(url, 'action', 'height=550,width=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes')
            document.searchform.setAttribute('target', 'action');
            document.searchform.setAttribute('onsubmit', '');
            document.searchform.submit();
        }
    </script>

    <form method=GET name="searchform" action="http://www.google.com/search">

        <input type=hidden name=ie value=UTF-8>
        <input type=hidden name=oe value=UTF-8>

        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

            <input type=text name=q id=q size=31 maxlength=255 value="">
            <input type=submit name=btnG value="Search" onclick="basicPopup('about:blank'); return false">

            <font size=-1>
                <input type=hidden name=domains value="google">
                <input type=hidden name=sitesearch value="google.com" checked>
            </font>

        </table>

    </form>
```

I have used the following SO question as a reference: [How do I submit an HTML form to a Popup windows with resize disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660810/how-do-i-submit-an-html-form-to-a-popup-windows-with-resize-disabled)